# "bin/magento setup:upgrade" taking too long time to complete

Tags: magento2.4, setup-upgrade, speedoptimization

I have 2 different servers and same magento243 setup in both servers.
In one server **setup:upgrade** is completed quickly, but in another server it takes about 15 minutes to complete upgrade command.

```
Server : Nginx
Php : 7.4
Magento Version : 2.4.3
```

Anyone have idea what actually problem is?

Comment: Check Db connect and check on which modules process getting some time to take.Check and disabled it if possible. Or might be server  I/O   has some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the var/vendor folder existing or not ?

If not then download Magento 2.4.3 and upload vendor folder in var/ directory.

then run again setup:upgrade command it's working.

Also, Check PHP variable like `memory limit and max_execution_time 18000, max_input_time 18000, max_input_vars 50000, memory_limit 4096M Also you can check var/log/ for error`